# Can bundler constrain a gem installation to a certain operating system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

I'm developing a Rails 3.1, and am using the default uglifier asset gem. That gem depends on execjs, which requires a JavaScript runtime. I develop on Mac OSX, so I never had trouble with it. Another developer uses Linux, which doesn't have a JavaScript runtime by default. So using therubyracer, a JavaScript runtime embedded in Ruby, works quite fine, but I'd like Bundler to install it only if the system is Linux. Can I specify this in the Gemfile so it'll only install in Linux and not Mac?

Answer (score 7):

you can do;

```
gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i
```

replacing the gem and the platform with appropriate ones in your case.

Comment: This still installs the gem, does it not? I'm looking for a way to skip it during a `bundle install` if it's not Linux.

Comment: @rubish Yes, it still installs it. `:require => false` is only used to prevent bundler from requiring the library at runtime, i.e., you require it manually in your own code.

Comment: @Jonathan C. Not `:require => false`, but `if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i` should have done the trick, How ever issue pointed out by @Luke Cowell, with Gemfile.lock is worth noting

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this approach is that if the OS X system updates the Gemfile.lock, the gem will be included. This become problematic if the other developer updates any gem in the gemfile as bundler will not include the gem when it calculates the dependencies.

My approach to solving this type of problem has been to manually install the gem I want and then require both:

```
begin
  require 'os-x-gem'
rescue LoadError
end
begin
  require 'linux-gem'
rescue LoadError
end
```

Comment: But this will fail, if user is on linux, as `require "os-x-gem"` will fail resulting in load error and linux gem will never be required. Both gems need their own begin rescue blocks.

Comment: excellent point, I missed that. I've updated the example to correct this.